# how to stop an Handler in android

Tags: android, handler, android-handler

i 've created an android application on which when one button clicks handler will activate an on every 2 second a toaster will appear. same on the other way i've a stop button from which i want to stop the running thread on clicking

This is my code

```
private final int  FIVE_SECONDS = 2000;


    public void scheduleSendLocation() {
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                sendLocation();          // this method will contain your almost-finished HTTP calls
                handler.postDelayed(this, FIVE_SECONDS);
            }
        }, FIVE_SECONDS);
    }


    protected void sendLocation() {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your Location is ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        btnShowLocation = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnShowLocation);
        stop = (Button) findViewById(R.id.stop);

        btnShowLocation.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View arg0) {        
                scheduleSendLocation();

            }
        });

        stop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View arg0) {        
        // what to write here
            }
        });

    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try calling the following code

```
    stop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View arg0) {        
            handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
        }
    });
```

Where `runnable` is the runnable which you added while calling postDelayed. Any pending posts of `runnable` will be removed that are in the message queue.

Comment: sir what's the argument for removeCallbacks()

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
stop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View arg0) {        
             myHandlerThread.interrupt();
             myHandlerThread = null;
        }
    });
```